# IMPORTRANGE to import a range of multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I need to reference a sheet (called Working) that is full of price and stock info.  I've created a new spreadsheet, and want to import values from the Working sheet without having to insert `=importrange` for every cell.

I'm using the following code:

`=IMPORTRANGE("1aHJ8wTbmJ.......","Working!A39")`

Is there a way to reference the Working sheet that is faster to achieve than doing it cell by cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, `IMPORTRANGE` [imports a range of cells from a specified spreadsheet.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

As shown in the documentation, the second parameter in the function is a reference to a *range* of the spreadsheet, and so all you need is to provide a valid reference to a range within that sheet, e.g.:

`=IMPORTRANGE("Sheet Url...", "Working!A:A")`